# Proper way to start application servers

Tags: redhat, ruby-on-rails, upstart

I'm not a server admin by any means...but run a few small apps and need to learn how things *should* work...

I start all my stuff manually; mostly rails with puma/thin.

When I reboot, I need to start my puma apps. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An application server is typically started as a system service. On RHEL 7 that would be with a [systemd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html) start-up script.

On previous RHEL versions that would have been by either including the start-up command in [**`/etc/init.d/rc.local`**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html) or a traditional SystemV style init script.

I'm not familiar enough with Ruby to know if that community has alternative conventions.